# jQuery method to identify the bottom of the page won't work

Tags: jquery, html

This code do absolutely the opposite things. It's identify the top of the page. What's the problem?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) == $(document).height()) {
    alert("bottom reached!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div style="height: 4000px">Scroll down!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Works in Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Well guys, the problem was that I did not write <!DOCTYPE html> at the beginning of my file. That's why $(window).height()) was equal to $(document).height()

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.

https://repl.it/Gypr/1

Not sure where you are creating this code, what browser you may be using or what.